# In microservices, using RestClient how to call url dynamically using application name?

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-8, microservices

I'm working on a UserService app that fetches data from Rating and Hotel services using Spring Boot. I want to replace hardcoded URLs with application names for dynamic service discovery.
Current approach (with hardcoded URLs):

```
List<Rating> ratingsOfUser = client.get().uri("http://localhost:8083/ratings/user/" + user.getUserId())
        .retrieve()
        .body(typeRef);
```

Desired approach (with application name):

```
List<Rating> ratingsOfUser = client.get().uri("http://RATING-SERVICE/ratings/user/" + user.getUserId())
        .retrieve()
        .body(typeRef);
```

Attempted solutions:

1. @LoadBalanced annotation with RestClient:

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfig {

   @Bean
   @LoadBalanced
   public RestClient restClient() {
       return RestClient.builder()
               .build();
   }
}
```

This didn't work.

2. WebClient with load balancing:

```
@Bean
public WebClient.Builder loadBalancedWebClientBuilder() {
    return WebClient.builder().filter(loadBalancerExchangeFilterFunction());
}
```

I added the spring-cloud-starter-loadbalancer dependency, but I'm getting a "Cannot resolve symbol 'WebClient'" error.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-loadbalancer</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Spring Boot version = 3.2.1

MyConfig.class

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfig {


    @Bean
    @LoadBalanced
    public RestClient restClient(){
        return RestClient.builder()
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public WebClient.Builder loadBalancedWebClientBuilder() {
        return WebClient.builder().filter(loadBalancerExchangeFilterFunction());
    }

}
```

getUser Method

```
 @Override
    public User getUser(String userId) {

        //get user from the db with the help of user Repo
        User user = userRepository.findById(userId)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("User not found: " + userId));
        // fetch Rating of the above user from Rating Service

        ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Rating>> typeRef = new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Rating>>() {};
     //   List<Rating> ratingsOfUser = client.get().uri("http://RATING-SERVICE/ratings/user/" +user.getUserId())
        List<Rating> ratingsOfUser = client.get().uri("http://localhost:8083/ratings/user/" +user.getUserId())
                .retrieve()
                .body(typeRef);

        // for each rating fetch Hotel

         List<Rating> ratingList = ratingsOfUser.stream().map(rating -> {
             //api call to get hotel service
             //Hotel hotels =  client.get().uri("http://HOTEL-SERVICE/hotels/"+rating.getHotelId())
             Hotel hotels =  client.get().uri("http://localhost:8081/hotels/"+rating.getHotelId())
               .retrieve()
                .body(new ParameterizedTypeReference<Hotel>() {});

          //set the hotel to the rating
           rating.setHotel(hotels);
          // return the rating
           return rating;

        }).collect(Collectors.toList());


        user.setRatings(ratingList);
        logger.info("{} ",ratingsOfUser);
        return user;
    }
```

Please let me know, if any additional information required. Thank you

Comment: Well, what do you use for service discovery?

Comment: am not using anything for service  discovery. For service Registry I used "spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server".

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use restclient with application name you have to use service discovery(Consul,Eureka btw eureka is deprecated) and register all apps what call each others.

Comment: can you please explain in little detail.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can read this Spring Docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-commons/reference/spring-cloud-commons/common-abstractions.html#rest-client-loadbalancer-client

And this is the configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration {

    @LoadBalanced
    @Bean
    RestClient.Builder restClientBuilder() {
        return RestClient.builder();
    }
}

public class MyClass {

    @Autowired
    private RestClient.Builder restClientBuilder;

    public String doOtherStuff() {
        return restClientBuilder.build().get().uri(URI.create("http://stores/stores")).retrieve().body(String.class);
    }
}
```